# how to find and append values in excel based on how cell begins?

Tags: excel

I have > 10000 address records in Excel with a range of input patterns but what I want to deal with is this:

```
 |4 example street     |    (house number, street name but no city)
```

Is it possible to write a query to fulfil:

- if cell *begins* with a number then append cell with name of city

Can this be done easily in Excel? R? SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, In which case give this a try..

This is assuming that your address data is in cell A1, and you city is in B1. Also I'm assuming you're using excel 2010 or later - I don't think NUMBERVALUE was available pre-2010.

=IFERROR(IF(AND(NUMBERVALUE(LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)))>1,NUMBERVALUE(LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)))<100),CONCATENATE(A1,", ",B1),A1),A1)

- The IFERROR will simply display the data in cell A1 if the formula causes an error.
- The AND checks the number is between 1 & 100 (change these values as appropriate
- The NUMBERVALUE converts the text returned from the LEFT into a number
- The LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)) returns all the text in A1 located before the space. Again, this could be changed to a double space, comma, combination of both etc. Just make sure they are in speech marks.
- The CONCATENATE puts the data from A1, followd by a comma and space, then adds the city from B1.

So if A1 = '22 John Street', and B1 = 'Bristol', the result would be '22 John Street, Bristol'
and if A1 = '18GreatRoad' (with no space) the result would remain the same as '18GreatRoad'.

Answer (score 0):

How is the address data formatted? Is there a consistent approach to commas/spaces between street name and address? I'm thinking you use =IF(left(A1,2)>0"&<"999,Right(A1,Find(",",A1)-1),FALSE) 
Or something to that effect. You could smarten it up to trim spaces or remove junk text by using trim or changing the -1 at the end of the find.

Comment: Or you could load it into SQL in a temporary table and pull it out again with a substring on the address field. Cba to right that out from my phone though!

Comment: Unfortunately, the data are historical and pretty messy. There are no commas or full stops, only a space between the house number and street name (or Lane, Road, Square). For those cells I am thinking I can still use a form of your suggestion though not sure what I base the "Right... Find" on? I'm not identifying a space or comma, only the end of the cell in these instances.